# Unfolding SimpleMapApp - Image files missing

Tags: java, unfoldingmap

I am working on an application which uses unfoldingmaps with processing.

Below is the sample code from unfolding in processing

```
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.*; 

UnfoldingMap map;

void setup() {
    size(800, 600, P2D);
    map = new UnfoldingMap(this);
    MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);
}

void draw() {
    map.draw();
}
```

This is the error message I am getting

```
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/1/2.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/2/3.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/2/2.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/2/1.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/3/1.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/3/2.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/1/3.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/3/3.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/0/2.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/2/0.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/1/0.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/0/3.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/0/1.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/0/0.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/3/0.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
The file "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/2/1/1.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
```

I tried hitting the url from the browser - it says image files have been moved. Should I get a dump of this in my local system? How does this work? Do these URLs work for others using unfolding?

Answer (score 7):

This is the modified version of example code.

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.Location;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;
public class HelloUnfoldingWorld extends PApplet {

    UnfoldingMap map;

    public void setup() {
        size(800, 600, OPENGL);

        map = new UnfoldingMap(this, new Google.GoogleMapProvider());
        map.zoomAndPanTo(10, new Location(52.5f, 13.4f));

        MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(0);
        map.draw();
    }

}
```

I have added

```
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;
```

and modified

```
map = new UnfoldingMap(this, new Google.GoogleMapProvider());
```

Now it is working

Comment: This solution solved the problem (which still exists with the example sketches of unfoldingmaps in processing). So could this be accepted as correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

For some weeks, the map tile service Unfolding uses as default did not respond properly as they moved to WikiMedia Labs. Now it redirects, and serves the tile images again.

Comment: This error still takes place when the unfolding-app-template-with-examples HelloUnfoldingWorld.java program. So I guess the redirection still does not take place. Or atleast the template examples don't have the latest code updated with the redirection